# Array.prototype methods affect multiple variables in function?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental about JavaScript. Any help would be appreciated.

In the below code, my function takes an array as an argument. It sets a new variable `newArr` equal to the `input` variable.

```js
input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4];

function test(input){
 var newArr = input;
  newArr.splice(0,1);
  return input;
};

console.log(test(input));
```

Now I call the `splice()` method on the new variable. I thought this would only affect the new variable, leaving the `input` variable unchanged.

Yet, when I return the `input` variable, it has been spliced in the same way as `newArr`.

The same thing happens with the `push()` method. Why is this? And how can you call these methods on one variable and not another?

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aaronmu30/hvk46ckd/4/)

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I was missing the fact that I need to clone the array, not just assign it to a new variable.

It seems like there are many ways to do this, one of which looks like this:

```js
input = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4];

function test(input){
  var newArr = input.slice(0); // clones array
  newArr.splice(0,1);
  return input;
};

console.log(test(input));
```

Answer (score 1):

In javascript a var that receive an object from another var isn't a copy, but a reference.

http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass

Answer (score 1):

Array assignment does not copy the array. Both `newArr` and `input` point to the same object.

Comment: I see. I was missing that. Thanks so much.